# Which CMS is this (from screenshot)?

Tags: cms

Does anyone know what CMS this is?

Thanks!!
[image: MA WebCenters Web Site Manager]

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's a proprietary system, developed by [these people](http://home.mawebcenters.com/).
If it's built off of some existing CMS, it's probably customized enough as to be proprietary anyway, though that doesn't seem quite what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the source of the page it might give you some clues.

Answer (score 1):

Install this extension in Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae and then open the site. The extension knows quite a few CMS systems, even obscure ones so there's a good chance it'll know about this one.